# Ruby on Rails equivalent to flush() in PHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a long running script (it runs for about 2 hours) display its progress and the coded in HTML updates as it runs rather than waiting until the script completes to show the entire result.

Having searched for SO, I've found an answer, which is to use `render stream: true` in the controller.  However, it doesn't work with my view for some reason.

Controller

```
def import
    @shelfunit = @discogs.get_user_folders(@user.username)
  #  above is API connector for Discogs-Wrapper Gem

    render stream: true
  end
```

View (erb)

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<% 
# set some variables
# write to database
%>
<h2>Status Update</h2>
<%
# For each do
    # set some variables
    # write to database
%>
    <h2>Status Update</h2>
<%
# End For each
%>
```

It's currently waiting until the script has finished to display anything at all, I'm getting no errors, but I want it to stream the view, and all the HTML as it reaches it rather than waiting.

Can anyone please advise where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This sounds like something that is better done by using a background job and ActionCable (websockets) rather than tying up your web thread for 2 hours. Streaming in this way is also really bad for performance in the client. Using `flush` in PHP was a good idea 10 years ago - the world has moved on.

Comment: It may be something that people might want to do as background, I do however want it to be foreground, to be frank, only the very first run would take that long, subsequent imports would take only a few minutes as the import would only be bringing the new information

Comment: Yeah, but its still a MAJOR scaling problem and pretty much the worst possible solution. Even using ajax and polling is a huge improvement.